# CodeIgniter pagination

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am using CodeIgniter pagination class, and everything works fine, but i want to show to the user only a few tables from my database. Currently i am using this code:

```
function index() {      
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $this->load->library('table');

            $this->table->set_heading('Id', 'The Title', 'The Content');

            $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci_helpbg/';
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('helps')->num_rows();
            $config['per_page'] = 5;
            $config['num_links'] = 20;
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';



            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $data['records'] = $this->db->get('helps', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));




        $data['main_content'] = 'index_view';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }
```

and i am using this code to display pagination in my view:

```
<?php echo $this->table->generate($records); ?>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

I want to show to the user only 'short_description' , 'description', 'photo_thumb' , and 'date' table fields.

Thank you.

Comment: Only on your pagination page or over more pages? please give some more information.

Comment: I want to display these table fields on my index view page, not the whole thing ( id ..... etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select specific fields
for example

```
$this->db->select('t1.name, t1.fname,t1.phone,t1.email');
```

and create role for users that which part you gona show to them.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a unique select statement for only pagination. something like:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1, table2, table3'); //if you don't want to use table4 or table5 just do not mention that in the statement.
```

after this add this to your controller where the pagination is.

```
$data['gettables'] = $this->yourmodel_gettables(); //the model with your select statement
```

Hope it helps.